# Xpath with combination of Preceding-sibling and following-sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to read the values from this screen( Sections appears dynamically it can be more than one). We have to read each field like Local Radios, MAC Address, Version from General Application Statistic and Default Geo Code from Legacy Configuration.. i got xapth to identify how many sections displayed. But unable to read the content under each section. i have to read them like key/value pair.. [image]Due to the structure of html(Below) I am having tough time to write xpath between two section like ...General Application Statistics and Legacy Configuration

```
<table class="tabletext">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large">Collector Information</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="tabletext">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:medium" colspan="2" align="left">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color:Navy; font-size:20px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; " width="700px">General Application Statistics</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Local Radios</td>
<td align="left">AA.5E.AZ.21.13.04[Z0136FBZ]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">MAC Address</td>
<td align="left">91-99-99-0C-66-B2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Version</td>
<td align="left">14.48.24.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size:medium" colspan="2" align="left">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color:Navy; font-size:20px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; " width="700px">Legacy Configuration</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:medium">Default Geo Code</td>
<td align="left">AF.ZA.QE.23.23.1F</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the xpath I am trying to fix.I am sure its buggy but can some one direct me how to resolve this..

```
//table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='Legacy Configuration']]/preceding-sibling::tr and following-sibling::tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='General Application Statistics']]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `xpath between two section`? Which element are you trying to select/click?

Comment: I am trying to fetch the elements between two sections in the html which i posted. for e.g. under General Application Statistics section. there are Local Radios, MAC Address, Version. those i am taking as keys and respective values into Dictionary (Robot FrameWork). So i am trying to fetch the elements between two sections with the help of xpath.. (initially i need count to see the no of Keys)

Comment: `findElement()` will return you only single node while `findElements()` will return you a `List` of nodes strictly following your `xpath`. How can you fetch `all the elements between two sections in the html` with n number of different tags?

Comment: Well Could you correct the xpath ? i am trying to get one but some where its failing or

Comment: I am unable to understand your `Usecase` properly. What is your exact manual step which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: we have to compare the values appears in this html with the values either from DB or from main screen. so we have to read the field::values from this page(sply under sections) then store them in the List/Dictionary them use them. see the attached image.. i jus took the screen shot of similar page.

Comment: For this Question, lets leave aside the second part `values either from DB or from main screen ...`. As far as `values appears in this html` is concerned, which value are you willing to `read`/`pick`/`extract`?

Comment: Yeah, I am g8 fan of your skills. thats you i am sure i gonna get right direction from you.  I am using Robot FrameWork (Not Java). However,logic would be same I need to read the elements appears under General Applications Statics and Legacy Configuration. I am using similar to Hash Map concept to get these values into it.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the values of  `Local Radios`, `MAC Address` and `Version` under `General Application Statistics` section?

Comment: i am trying to find out no of values under each section.. like this  ${No_Of_Key_Value} =  get matching xpath count  //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='General Application Statics']]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td

Comment: Yes, i am trying to retrieve them in the for loop

Comment: ${No_Of_Key_Value} =  get matching xpath count  //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='${Section_Header_Name}']]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td
    : FOR  ${Count}   IN Range 1 ${No_Of_Key_Value}
    \  ${Key} =  Get Value   //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='${Section_Header_Name}']]/following-sibling::tr[${Count}]/td[1]
    \  ${Value} =  Get Value   //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='${Section_Header_Name}']]/following-sibling::tr[${Count}]/td[2]

Comment: //table[2]/tbody/tr[td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[normalize-space(text())='General Application Statistics']]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td.... This xpath gives me both key and Value .. (like field and value) but i want find the list of field first.. (for which i need xpath.. and need your help) if xpath is working then ..my script is completed.. that is only missing piece.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162652/discussion-between-debanjanb-and-bbk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve each field like `Local Radios`, `MAC Address`, `Version` from **General Application Statistic** and the field `Default Geo Code` from **Legacy Configuration** you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> all_items1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='tabletext']/tbody//tr//td//table//tbody//tr//td[contains(.,'General Application Statistics')]//following::td"));
List<String> properties = new ArrayList<String>(3);
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(3);
for (int i=0;i<all_items.size();i=i+2)
    properties.add(all_items.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for (int j=1;j<all_items.size();j=j+2)
    values.add(all_items.get(j).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for (int k=0;k<properties.size();k++)
    System.out.println("Property " + properties.get(k) + " has a value of " + values.get(k));
List<WebElement> all_items2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='tabletext']/tbody//tr//td//table//tbody//tr//td[contains(.,'Legacy Configuration')]//following::td"));
List<String> properties = new ArrayList<String>(1);
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(1);
for (int i=0;i<all_items.size();i=i+2)
    properties.add(all_items.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for (int j=1;j<all_items.size();j=j+2)
    values.add(all_items.get(j).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for (int k=0;k<properties.size();k++)
    System.out.println("Property " + properties.get(k) + " has a value of " + values.get(k));
```

Comment: I am gonna try this this now

Comment: I have kept the `xpath` flexible to detect both the strings `General Application Statistic` and `Legacy Configuration`. While you pass `General Application Statistic` the `ExpectedConditions` will be `numberOfElementsToBe(By(xpath), 6)` and when you pass `Legacy Configuration` the `ExpectedConditions` will be `numberOfElementsToBe(By(xpath), 2)`. In both the cases only the `String` (General Application Statistic/Legacy Configuration) and the number of elements changes (6/2).

Comment: List<WebElement> all_items = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.xpath("//table[@class='tabletext']/tbody//tr//td//table//tbody//tr//td[contains(.,'General Application Statistics')]//following::td"), 6)); returning 11 items. I want to fetch only three fields.

Comment: What if i want to fetch only field labels like Local Radios, MAC Address and Version. What should be the xpath?? can you suggest please

Comment: This helps alot to fetch the property tags along with values

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged **Robot Framework**, i'll give a robot specific solution here:

```
${legal_key}=      Get Text    xpath://td[text()='Local Radios']
${legal_value}=    Get Text    xpath://td[text()='Local Radios']/following-sibling::td
```

Similarly for all the other fields you want.